# Can you simplify jQuery code, so i became more dynamic

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic

Im afraid, when i use the code:

```
<div id="sentence_xx"></div>
```

that i always have to print a lot of jquery code.

I can see the code in this link : 
http://jsfiddle.net/hBRNy/2/


the problem is that, there will be al lot of div sentences

```
<div id="sentence_xx"></div>
```

and every time that i want to print it, i have to print the whole jquery block whit it for every **< div>**.

does someone knows how i can solve this? because the id's that the jquery generate must be unique and I hoped that this could be more flexible but dont know how.

kind regards

---

I found a solution By using jquery wildcards (you cant replace the id's by classes, because the ui.jquery wouldn't work anymore:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // For everey id, started with sentence_  (the sentences which I want)
    $('[id^=sentence_]').each(function() {

    // strip the id until i have the number only (sentence_ is a static value)
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var toRemove = "sentence_";
    var id = currentId.replace(toRemove,'');

    //replace all the characters by "</li> <li class=\"ui-widget-content_"+id+"\">"
    var text = $("#"+currentId).text().trim().split("").join("</li> <li class=\"ui-widget-content_"+id+"\">");
    $("#"+currentId).html("<li class=\"ui-widget-content_"+id+"\">" + text + "</li>");

    //create a <ol> after the div selectable_xx
    $('<ol class="selectable_style" id="selectable_'+id+'"></ol>').insertAfter("#"+currentId);

    // remove the value of the div and place them into the <ol>
   $('.ui-widget-content_'+id+'').clone().appendTo("#selectable_"+id);
    $('#sentence_'+id).remove();

    //replace all the " " by non breaking spaces 
    $('#selectable_'+id+' li').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).text().replace(' ', '&nbsp;'));
    });


     //attache the function for selecting items and put the character place into the next span
        $( "#selectable_"+id ).selectable({
            stop: function() {
                var woord ="" ;
                var result = $( "#selectable_"+id ).next('span').empty();
                $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                    var index = $( "#selectable_"+ id +" li" ).index( this );
                    result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
                    letter = index + 1;
                    woord += letter+'';
                });

                }
            });
        });     
    });
</script>
```

If you want to play with it, i have updated the code 
http://jsfiddle.net/hBRNy/16/

Comment: Belongs on: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes instead and try to make your code more modular to avoid repeated code for new elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use css `class'es` for elements that repeat them selfs.

so if you have many elements with same functionality like this

so you can do something like like this:

```
$(".my-class").html("<a href='#'>Me!</a>");
```

And this will attach same behaviour to all elements with class "my-class"

For generating content like html you should use something like handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/ this lets you define templates and render them in javascripts

something like this

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{name}} </a>
```

becomes this

```
(for var object = {name: "my blog", url: "http://no-idea.com"})

<a href="http://no-idea.com">my blog</a>
```

(it is rewritten my old post and i see there are some display bugs)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the class posts but if you do need to preserve the sentence number you could store them on the node using [HTML 5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).  That way you wouldn't have to worry about duplicate id attributes and you would still get the hooks for CSS that you need.

```
<div data-sentence="xx"></div>
```

Select them all in CSS with:

```
div[data-sentence] { foo: bar; }
```

or in jQuery with:

```
$('div[data-sentence]')
```

But if you don't need to preserve the sentence number just go with a class as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Did my best :/ no hating

```
$(document)
.ready(function () {
$("[id^=sentence_]")
    .each(function () {
    var a = $(this)
        .attr("id"),
        b = "sentence_",
        c = a.replace(b, ""),
        d = $("#" + a)
            .text()
            .trim()
            .split("")
            .join('</li> <li class="ui-widget-content_' + c + '">');
    $("#" + a)
        .html('<li class="ui-widget-content_' + c + '">' + d + "</li>"), $('<ol class="selectable_style" id="selectable_' + c + '"></ol>')
        .insertAfter("#" + a), $(".ui-widget-content_" + c + "")
        .clone()
        .appendTo("#selectable_" + c), $("#sentence_" + c)
        .remove(), $("#selectable_" + c + " li")
        .each(function () {
        $(this)
            .html($(this)
            .text()
            .replace(" ", "&nbsp;"))
    }), $("#selectable_" + c)
        .selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var a = "",
                b = $("#selectable_" + c)
                    .next("span")
                    .empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this)
                .each(function () {
                var d = $("#selectable_" + c + " li")
                    .index(this);
                b.append(" #" + (d + 1)), letter = d + 1, a += letter + ""
            })
        }
    })
})
})
```